# How can I get a play or click event to a video element using Angular 7?

Tags: javascript, angular

I inherited a project that needs some minor analytics, more specifically, video plays analytics.

It's an Angular project that gets a html body from a SQL server.

It parses a string and injects in a page. So I can't add extra html to solve this issue, I can only add some Angular code.

Current analytics is Matomo, I'm using ngx-matomo to monitor views and visits.

AFAIK when a video is played I need to send the notification to the server, but the thing is, how do I get the event when a video is played?

My jQuery habits would say that monitoring events and waiting for a video element would suffice, but here's the gist, I can't get click events on video elements.

I wrote this small piece of code that mimics what I'm trying to do?

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION, ViewChild} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div (click)="anyClick($event)" style="padding: 10px">
      <div> not the video </div>
      <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="http://download.blender.org/peach/trailer/trailer_400p.ogg" type="video/ogg">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </div>
  `,
})

export class App {  

  anyClick(event: String) {
    console.log(event);
  }  
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

There's a plnkr here http://plnkr.co/edit/ALk16AiaHtgqYYrw

If you click anywhere on the page, you'll get the event on the console, but the same is not true if you click the video, which is the event I need.

I can attach a listener to a play event using a tag like this

```
 ngOnInit(){
    let video = document.querySelector('video');
    video.onplay = (event) => {
      console.log('The Boolean paused property is now false. Either the ' + 
      'play() method was called or the autoplay attribute was toggled.');
    };
  }
```

If worked on Plunker, but it *feels* wrong...

Specifying the issue with more details:

The HTML file is actually just a

```
<div [innerHTML]="innerHTML"></div>
```

The component TS is

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Product } from 'src/app/entities/product';
import { Version } from 'src/app/entities/version';
import { ProductService } from '../product.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.scss']
})
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() product: Product;
  @Output() load = new EventEmitter<{ title: string, href: string }>();
  conteudo$: Observable<Version>;
  innerHTML: SafeHtml;

  constructor(
    private productService: ProductService,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {    
    var pathToLoad;

    this.productService.getVersion(pathToLoad).subscribe(version => {
      this.innerHTML = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(version.conteudo);

      const el = document.createElement('html');
      el.innerHTML = version.conteudo;
      const sections = el.getElementsByTagName('section');
      for (let i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
        const section = sections.item(i);
        if (section.hasAttribute('id')) {

          this.load.emit({
            title: section.getElementsByTagName('h2').item(0).textContent,
            href: section.getAttribute('id')
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: If you get a reference to the video element, you should theoretically be able to listen to the "onplay" and "onpause" events emitted from the video element. I'll try to provide some code examples soon. :)

Comment: https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#mediaevents

Comment: You posted the javascript solution. If you want to try to find an angular solution, then post the HTML that the server sends to the app.

Answer (score 7):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play_event
 the play event doesn't bubble.  In your plunker, add event binding to your video tag

```
<video (play)="anyClick($event)"
```

Comment: The html is parsed from a database, I cannot add anything to the video tag.

Comment: You have shown above that you can use javascript to attach a listener to a play event.  That seems fine.  Do you want a Angular way of doing it? If so, then could you post the HTML that is coming from the server?

Comment: I'll try that. It seems everyone in my company is doing home office, VPN servers are overloaded. And yes! I want an Angular way of doing it!

Comment: parse the information you need to reconstruct the information you need out of the html string to create a proper angular template. then next phase is to alter your server to return html or json optionally depending on request headers

Comment: Could you give me more info about that?

I updated the question to show where the HTML is coming from, but you seem to be asking me to parse the HTML before returning it from the server...?

Comment: if you control the server, then fix your server so it's not returning an HTML string, instead an object with the needed properties to construct your video tag like `{src: 'video.url.com'}` and whatever else. On the server you check the content header, if it wants html or json, and return accordingly. if you don't control the server, write a parser on your front end that finds the needed directives from the returned html and use those to construct your angular element.

Comment: Welp, the component has its innerHTML as SafeHTML so any change to it gets stripped out. Parsing the html and then passing it to the front doesn't seem like a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **onplay**="**script or function call**"

```
 <video width="320" onplay="console.log('hello im playing')" height="240" controls>
   <source src="http://download.blender.org/peach/trailer/trailer_400p.ogg" type="video/ogg">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
```

If you are receiving **html from the server** and it is stored in a **string** variable like

```
 let htmlString=`<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="http://download.blender.org/peach/trailer/trailer_400p.ogg" 
  type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>`;
```

You can do add the **onplay** inside the string like this

```
htmlString.replace(/(video)/,"$1 onplay='onPlay($event)'");
```

HTML:

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlString"></div>
```

and then

```
onPlay($event:any){
  console.log($event.target.id);
  console.log($event.target.width);
}
```

Run this code below in js

```js
let htmlString=`<video width="320" id="vid20" height="240" controls>
<source src="http://download.blender.org/peach/trailer/trailer_400p.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>`;
document.querySelector("#main").innerHTML=htmlString.replace(/(video)/,"$1 onplay='onPlay(event)'");;

function onPlay(event){
      console.clear();
      console.log(event.target.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: Please don't use w3schools, instead, consider linking to the official MDN documentation. See this question from Meta StackOverflow for more info: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280478/6782707

Comment: Sure Eric.. I removed the reference now

Comment: I can't add the extra play event, the html comes from a database.

Comment: Depends on the page that is retrieved from the database, might be one, might be ten.

Comment: How are you rendering it programatically after you receiving html from server? Are you using [innerHTML]?

Comment: do NOT do this in angular. this post is top to bottom bad angular practices

Comment: well if you can suggest me , i will do the changes accordingly @bryan60

Comment: @bryan60 I don't get it, what is supposed to be done in this case?

Comment: @Supercool. it is set using innerHTML, but the recomendation of htmlString.replace(/(video)/,"$1 onplay='onPlay($event)'"); doesn't seem right, doing a regex replace doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: Will you point out the reasons why it is not a good idea.It just eases the things.